# getting error - TypeError: fetch failed The moviedb api [NEXTJS Api]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, themoviedb-api

[please enter this link to see the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flLGu.png)  I got the ((Server Error
TypeError: fetch failed)) when I was trying to use themoviedb api.
this is my index.js file. I have checked everything for many times from scratch. But I get this
error every time I run my app. For more information: I am cloning hulu website with the help of a video tutorial.

```
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import Header from '../components/Header'
    import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
    import Results from '../components/Results'
    import requests from '../utils/requests'


    export default function Home(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>movie-website</title>
        <meta name="description" content="movie website" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <Navbar />
      <Results />
    </div>
     )
    }

    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const genre = context.query.genre;
    const request = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3${requests[genre]?.url || requests.fetchTrending.url
    }`
    ).then((res) => res.json());

    return {
    props: {
      results: request.results,
      },
     };
    }
```

this is my request.js file:

```
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;

const requests = {
fetchTrending: {
    title: "Trending",
    url: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
},
fetchTopRated: {
    title: "Top Rated",
    url: `/movie/top_rated?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
},
fetchActionMovies: {
    title: "Action",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=28`
},
fetchComedyMovies: {
    title: "Comedy",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=35`
},
fetchHorrorMovies: {
    title: "Horror",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=27`
},
fetchRomanceMovies: {
    title: "Romance",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=10749`
},
fetchMystery: {
    title: "Mystery",
    url: `/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_genres=9648`
 },
}
export default requests;
```

I also have a file named .env.local which I keep my API_KEY in it.

Comment: Please provide more information on your error. What's the message that the server tells you?

Comment: ok. I shared a link which contains the image of error

Comment: it seems like you are fetch api call is failing.. add .catch block to your fetch req, see what error you are getting ?